# Window HTTP IO Completion port

Tags: c++, c, windows, httpserver, io-completion-ports

I was going through the IO Completion port documentation of Windows programming with relation to the Windows HTTP Server API.

So in the HTTP Server API, we have a queue which is an abstraction over the responses/requests. We have the handle to the queue to get the relevant information.

If i am to associate a IO Completion port with this, does that mean that i have use the queue as the handle? Will this not reduce the granularity? Can't i associate a IO Completion port with each request rather than with the complete queue.

Detailed Query:
We register for certain URL using a request queue in windows http server api. So there maybe lots of requests on a queue. How can i associate a IO Completion port with the each request/response rather than with the Queue itself.

IO Completition:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363862(v=vs.85).aspx

Queue Documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364483(v=vs.85).aspx

Receive a Request:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364495(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

The IO port is associated with the queue handle. The underlying request and response are not associated with the IO port.

Overlapped structure is used for passing relevant information about response and request.